# How to animate top % after a delay?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a div that has an initial position at the middle of the window. After a 3 second delay I want it to slide to the top of the screen. How is this achieved?

Here is what I have so far (https://jsfiddle.net/5m363gt1/):

HTML

```
<div id="red"></div>
```

CSS

```
#red{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#red").delay(3000).animate({top:'0%'},1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function and use setTimeout method from jQuery:

```
var onTop = function() {
    $("#red").animate({'top' : '0'});
};

    setTimeout(function(){
    onTop();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: You have to select a jQuery Library on the jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to trigger the function too; assuming that your 3 second delay is from the time the page is loaded, use something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dartonw/11anm8ce/